# 8 Queens Problem

Tags: statistics, soft-question

In how many ways can 8 queens be placed on a chess board such that none of them are threatening each other.

Comment: Have you tried googling on "8 queens problem"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called the 8-Queens problem and can be generalized to the n-queens problem, the solution is 92 different ways.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_queens_puzzle#Solution_construction
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/QueensProblem.html